# How to update the Recylerview View items after displayed First Json URL In android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I having a problem update the Item in Recycler View.I will explain clearly about my problem.

I am using two Json URL's first Json URL can send the items to model class.
after completed this called the adapter, then update the second Json URL items with the adapter by using setter model class.

so that's why called adapter.notifyitemchanged, but only one time can updated items next time while looping  doesn't update the items display empty for second time.

Code:

```
 public void servicecallsingle(String list, final int pin) {
 url = Constants.singleproducturl + list;


 JsonObjectRequest request1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
         JSONObject response1 = response;

         if (response1 != null) {
             //   int status=jsonObject.optInt("status");
             String status = response1.optString("status");
             if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) { //check the status 200 or not
                 try {
                     productpath = response1.getString("productPath");
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 try {
                     JSONObject responses = response1.getJSONObject("response");
                     jsonarray = responses.getJSONArray(DATA);

                     if (jsonarray.length() > 0) {
                         // looping through json and adding to movies list
                         for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                             item = new CartItemoriginal();
                             JSONObject product = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                             cartpid = product.getString("product_id");
                             cartproductname = product.getString("product_name");
                             cartaliasname = product.getString("product_alias");
                             cartprice = product.getString("mrp_price");
                             String sp = product.getString("selling_price");
                             String op = product.getString("offer_selling_price");
                             sellerid = product.getString("seller_id");
                             JSONArray pimg = product.getJSONArray("product_images");
                             JSONObject firstimg = pimg.getJSONObject(0);
                             cartimg = firstimg.getString("original_res");
                             String[] img2 = cartimg.split("\\.");
                             String imagone = productpath + sellerid + '/' + img2[0] + '(' + '2' + '0' + '0' + ')' + '.' + img2[1];
                             String Quantity = product.getString("product_max_add");
                             String minqty = product.getString("product_min_add");
                             int qty = Integer.parseInt(Quantity);

                             /***  calculation  ***/
                             Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                             String ts = tsLong.toString();
                             int ts1 = Integer.parseInt(ts);
                             String startdate1 = product.getString("offer_selling_start_date");
                             String endate1 = product.getString("offer_selling_end_date");

                             if (("".equals(startdate1)) && ("".equals(endate1))) {
                                 // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"wrong statemnt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 if (cartprice.equalsIgnoreCase(sp)) {
                                     double d = Double.parseDouble(cartprice);
                                     int mrp = (int) d;
                                     price = String.valueOf(mrp);
                                 } else {
                                     double s = Double.parseDouble(sp);
                                     int sales = (int) s;
                                     price = String.valueOf(sales);

                                 }
                             } else {

                                 int startdate = Integer.parseInt(startdate1);
                                 int endate2 = Integer.parseInt(endate1);

                                 if (ts1 > startdate && ts1 < endate2) {
                                     double offer = Double.parseDouble(op);
                                     int offers = (int) offer;
                                     price = String.valueOf(offers);
                                 } else {
                                     if (cartprice.equalsIgnoreCase(sp)) {
                                         double d = Double.parseDouble(cartprice);
                                         int mrp = (int) d;
                                         price = String.valueOf(mrp);
                                     } else {
                                         double s = Double.parseDouble(sp);
                                         int sales = (int) s;
                                         price = String.valueOf(sales);
                                     }
                                 }
                             }

                             item.setProductname(cartproductname);
                             item.setQty(1);
                             item.setProductimg(imagone);
                             item.setMaxquantity(Quantity);
                             item.setAliasname(cartaliasname);
                             item.setPrice(price);
                             item.setMinquantity(minqty);
                             item.setProductid(cartpid);
                             cart.add(item);


                             // cart.add(new CartItemoriginal(imagone,cartproductname,cartaliasname,1,Quantity,minqty,price,cartpid));

                         }
                     }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

             } // condtion check the status 200
             else // this is if status falied in runtime
             {
                 Toast.makeText(CartItems.this, "Status Failed in Banner Page check ur network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }


             // llm = new LinearLayoutManager(CartItems.this);

             MainLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             final CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage layoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage(CartItems.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
             recyleitems.setHasFixedSize(false);
             recyleitems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
             cartadapter = new CartlistAdapter(cart, CartItems.this);
             Log.i(String.valueOf(cartadapter), "cartadapter");
             recyleitems.setAdapter(cartadapter);
             recyleitems.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
             myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             cartadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }

         String id = cartpid;
         String selleid = sellerid;
         final int pinnum = pin;
         String pinurl = "http://192.168.0.33/sharpswebsite3/qcrest1.0/?type=pinCodeCheck&result=json&product_id=" + id + "&seller_id=" + selleid + "&pinCode=" + pinnum;
         JsonObjectRequest request2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, pinurl, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONObject responsesecond) {
                 JSONObject response2 = responsesecond;
                 // do something with response1 & response here...
                 if (response2 != null) {
                     //   int status=jsonObject.optInt("status");
                     String status = response2.optString("status");
                     if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) { //check the status 200 or not
                         try {
                             JSONObject responses = response2.getJSONObject("response");
                             jsonarray = responses.getJSONArray(DATA);
                             if (jsonarray.length() > 0) {
                                 Log.i(String.valueOf(jsonarray.length()), "message");
                                 // looping through json and adding to movies list
                                 for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray.length(); j++) {
                                     JSONObject product = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);
                                     process = product.getString("process");
                                     Message = product.getString("message");
                                     if (process.equalsIgnoreCase("success") && Message.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                                         cartdelivery = product.getString("delivery");
                                         cartshippingcharge = product.getString("shipping_charge");
                                         String pincode = product.getString("pincode");

                                         /**************************calculation of shipping days**************************/

                                         int day = Integer.parseInt(cartdelivery);
                                         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                         String dayNumberSuffix = getDayNumberSuffix(day);
                                         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM d'" + dayNumberSuffix + "', yyyy");

                                         String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

                                         try {
                                             c.setTime(sdf.parse(currentDateandTime));
                                         } catch (ParseException e) {
                                             e.printStackTrace();
                                         }
                                         c.add(Calendar.DATE, day);
                                         Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
                                         currentDateandTime = sdf.format(resultdate);
                                         Log.d(String.valueOf(currentDateandTime), "shipping days");
                                         cart.get(j).setDelivery("Standard delivery by" + " " + currentDateandTime);
                                         cart.get(j).setShippincharge(cartshippingcharge);
                                         cart.get(j).setSellername("richard feloboune");

                                         cartadapter.notifyItemChanged(j);
                                         cartadapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(j, cart.size());

                                     } else {
                                         // cart2.add(new Cartitemoringinaltwo("Seller doesn't deliver to this item to"+" "+ String.valueOf(pinnum)));
                                         cart.get(j).setError("Seller doesn't deliver to this item to" + " " + String.valueOf(pinnum));
                                         cartadapter.notifyItemChanged(j);
                                     }
                                 }
                             }

                         } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         // stopping swipe refresh
                         // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                     } // condtion check the status 200
                     else // this is if status falied in runtime
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(CartItems.this, "Status Failed in Banner Page check ur network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 }



                 pincheck();
             }

         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
             }
         });
         AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request2);

     }


 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
     }
 });
 AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request1);
```

}

Note: While looping first time can set the item in setter model class but second couldn't set the item to model class.

Anyone solve this problem glad to appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Adapter init with first data you feed him in constructor, so `notifydatasetchange()` is not enough, you should change `ArrayList<Model>` items manually. another important thing is about you should not check `convertView == null` in `getView()` Override method.

Comment: ArrayList<Model> item manually how to change that can u please tell that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is volley doesn't wait for the request to be completed. So as the first call is made within seconds other call will be also made. So, you need to create an interface which will be called when the first webservice is called, and than in interface call other webservice and than notifyDataSet.

```
     public void servicecallsingle(String list, final int pin) {
    url = Constants.singleproducturl + list;


  JsonObjectRequest request1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     JSONObject response1 = response;

     if (response1 != null) {
         //   int status=jsonObject.optInt("status");
         String status = response1.optString("status");
         if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) { //check the status 200 or not
             try {
                 productpath = response1.getString("productPath");
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            parseJson(response1, new  WebServiceCallBack{
            public void getWebserviceCallBack(){
            // Call another webservice here
          String id = cartpid;
     String selleid = sellerid;
     final int pinnum = pin;
     String pinurl = "http://192.168.0.33/sharpswebsite3/qcrest1.0/?type=pinCodeCheck&result=json&product_id=" + id + "&seller_id=" + selleid + "&pinCode=" + pinnum;
     JsonObjectRequest request2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, pinurl, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONObject responsesecond) {
             JSONObject response2 = responsesecond;
             // do something with response1 & response here...
             if (response2 != null) {
                 //   int status=jsonObject.optInt("status");
                 String status = response2.optString("status");
                 if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) { //check the status 200 or not
                     try {
                         JSONObject responses = response2.getJSONObject("response");
                         jsonarray = responses.getJSONArray(DATA);
                         if (jsonarray.length() > 0) {
                             Log.i(String.valueOf(jsonarray.length()), "message");
                             // looping through json and adding to movies list
                             for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray.length(); j++) {
                                 JSONObject product = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);
                                 process = product.getString("process");
                                 Message = product.getString("message");
                                 if (process.equalsIgnoreCase("success") && Message.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                                     cartdelivery = product.getString("delivery");
                                     cartshippingcharge = product.getString("shipping_charge");
                                     String pincode = product.getString("pincode");

                                     /**************************calculation of shipping days**************************/

                                     int day = Integer.parseInt(cartdelivery);
                                     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                     String dayNumberSuffix = getDayNumberSuffix(day);
                                     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM d'" + dayNumberSuffix + "', yyyy");

                                     String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

                                     try {
                                         c.setTime(sdf.parse(currentDateandTime));
                                     } catch (ParseException e) {
                                         e.printStackTrace();
                                     }
                                     c.add(Calendar.DATE, day);
                                     Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
                                     currentDateandTime = sdf.format(resultdate);
                                     Log.d(String.valueOf(currentDateandTime), "shipping days");
                                     cart.get(j).setDelivery("Standard delivery by" + " " + currentDateandTime);
                                     cart.get(j).setShippincharge(cartshippingcharge);
                                     cart.get(j).setSellername("richard feloboune");

                                     cartadapter.notifyItemChanged(j);
                                     cartadapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(j, cart.size());

                                 } else {
                                     // cart2.add(new Cartitemoringinaltwo("Seller doesn't deliver to this item to"+" "+ String.valueOf(pinnum)));
                                     cart.get(j).setError("Seller doesn't deliver to this item to" + " " + String.valueOf(pinnum));
                                     cartadapter.notifyItemChanged(j);
                                 }
                             }
                         }

                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     // stopping swipe refresh
                     // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    } // condtion check the status 200
                 else // this is if status falied in runtime
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(CartItems.this, "Status Failed in Banner Page check ur network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }



             pincheck();
         }

     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
         }
     });
          AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request2);

 }


  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
 @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
 }
      });
             AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request1);

            });
             }

         } // condtion check the status 200
         else // this is if status falied in runtime
         {
             Toast.makeText(CartItems.this, "Status Failed in Banner Page check ur network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }


         // llm = new LinearLayoutManager(CartItems.this);

         MainLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         final CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage layoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage(CartItems.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
         recyleitems.setHasFixedSize(false);
         recyleitems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
         cartadapter = new CartlistAdapter(cart, CartItems.this);
         Log.i(String.valueOf(cartadapter), "cartadapter");
         recyleitems.setAdapter(cartadapter);
         recyleitems.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
         myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         cartadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }






      public void parseJson(JSONObject response1,  WebServiceCallBack       webserviceCallBack){
       try {
                 JSONObject responses = response1.getJSONObject("response");
                 jsonarray = responses.getJSONArray(DATA);

                 if (jsonarray.length() > 0) {
                     // looping through json and adding to movies list
                     for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                         item = new CartItemoriginal();
                         JSONObject product = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                         cartpid = product.getString("product_id");
                         cartproductname = product.getString("product_name");
                         cartaliasname = product.getString("product_alias");
                         cartprice = product.getString("mrp_price");
                         String sp = product.getString("selling_price");
                         String op = product.getString("offer_selling_price");
                         sellerid = product.getString("seller_id");
                         JSONArray pimg = product.getJSONArray("product_images");
                         JSONObject firstimg = pimg.getJSONObject(0);
                         cartimg = firstimg.getString("original_res");
                         String[] img2 = cartimg.split("\\.");
                         String imagone = productpath + sellerid + '/' + img2[0] + '(' + '2' + '0' + '0' + ')' + '.' + img2[1];
                         String Quantity = product.getString("product_max_add");
                         String minqty = product.getString("product_min_add");
                         int qty = Integer.parseInt(Quantity);

                         /***  calculation  ***/
                         Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                         String ts = tsLong.toString();
                         int ts1 = Integer.parseInt(ts);
                         String startdate1 = product.getString("offer_selling_start_date");
                         String endate1 = product.getString("offer_selling_end_date");

                         if (("".equals(startdate1)) && ("".equals(endate1))) {
                             // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"wrong statemnt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             if (cartprice.equalsIgnoreCase(sp)) {
                                 double d = Double.parseDouble(cartprice);
                                 int mrp = (int) d;
                                 price = String.valueOf(mrp);
                             } else {
                                 double s = Double.parseDouble(sp);
                                 int sales = (int) s;
                                 price = String.valueOf(sales);

                             }
                         } else {

                             int startdate = Integer.parseInt(startdate1);
                             int endate2 = Integer.parseInt(endate1);

                             if (ts1 > startdate && ts1 < endate2) {
                                 double offer = Double.parseDouble(op);
                                 int offers = (int) offer;
                                 price = String.valueOf(offers);
                             } else {
                                 if (cartprice.equalsIgnoreCase(sp)) {
                                     double d = Double.parseDouble(cartprice);
                                     int mrp = (int) d;
                                     price = String.valueOf(mrp);
                                 } else {
                                     double s = Double.parseDouble(sp);
                                     int sales = (int) s;
                                     price = String.valueOf(sales);
                                 }
                             }
                         }

                         item.setProductname(cartproductname);
                         item.setQty(1);
                         item.setProductimg(imagone);
                         item.setMaxquantity(Quantity);
                         item.setAliasname(cartaliasname);
                         item.setPrice(price);
                         item.setMinquantity(minqty);
                         item.setProductid(cartpid);
                         cart.add(item);


                         // cart.add(new       CartItemoriginal(imagone,cartproductname,cartaliasname,1,Quantity,minqty,price,cartpid));

                     }
                 }
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();}


                 webserviceCallBack.getWebserviceCallBack();

                 }



                 public interface WebServiceCallBack{
        public void getWebserviceCallBack()
     }
```

Comment: for second one webservice   have to create interface then i will call to first webservice

Comment: Yes, you can do it any how you want. Did this thing work??

Comment: It will work. Cheers !! If it does do give me positive vote :-)

Comment: but i don't understand do i create separate class for second webservice,before i got problem in second webservice can't updated second item but for first item can update in for loop

Comment: As soon as you get the sucess in first webservice parse the data and get back using callback method and than call the another webservice inside the onResponse of first webservice and than you will its response, and you can parse it.

Comment: I have created  seperate function then i called in first webserviced  but nothing will worked,same like that before only 1st item only update,second item is not updated display empty

Comment: can u explain your code, i don't understand proper way

Comment: public void parseData(WebServiceCallBack webserviceCallBack, JsonObject response){
//parseData
webserviceCallBack.getWebserviceCallBack();
} how to parse over here

Comment: parsing is as per your structure of json. Means where to set your values

Comment: I got some error while using interface by using second webservice call

Comment: can u change my code as like this example, because i am getting error

Comment: try it now @kanimozhi

Comment: Something missing closing bracket, first on response doesn't close the bracket properly,i am doing right now that

Comment: parseJson(response1, new WebServiceCallBack { for this closing bracket is it correct  like this    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
                            }
                        });

Comment: that you can handle it

Comment: parsejson closing make me confusing becoz already first onresponse has error listener close bracket again parse json got error uexpected token

Comment: I solved everything, but after i run unfortunately got same response

Comment: I got null object refrenece  item if i use like in this code